# Must know tactics for Blanka

Tags: street-fighter-iv

So, my Blanka is pretty weak right now.  What are some of the key things I need to use to be a good Blanka player?  For example:

1. What is Blanka's poke(s)?
2. How do I keep people from hammering on me when I'm getting up (is this called a wake-up game?)
3. Should I be keeping the pressure on or should I be turtling?
4. What moves have the least number of frames / highest priority?
5. Nice bread-and-butter combos?

I'm probably missing stuff, so please enlighten me! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here's](http://mycheats.1up.com/view/section/3163881/25962/street_fighter_4/xbox_360) a 1UP article on Blanka.

Also, here are some excerpts from the article:

> #### Strengths
>
> Very quick and tricky, enables him to punish and mix up his opponent in a number of ways
>   Great assortment of command normals to help him deal with numerous situations
>   Ultra does great chip damage, hits low then high so great for using on unsuspecting opponents.
>
> #### Weaknesses
>
> Limited combos mean most of his damage comes from single attacks and throws.
>   Cannot juggle into Ultra like some other characters can, and the Ultra itself is a bit of a gimmick once people understand it's tricks.
>
> #### Notable Normal Moves
>
> - Standing Hard Punch
> - Crouching Hard Punch
> - Down-Forward Hard Punch
> - Crouching Hard Kick
>
> ### Combos
>
> **Crouching LK, Standing LP, Hard Punch Rolling Attack**
>   Standard close range combo. Useful after you cross up with jumping MK.
>
> **Crouching Medium Kick cancel into Hard Punch Rolling Attack or Hard Kick Vertical Roll**
>   A combo to use when you are too far to land the crouching LK combo, and you can land either his Rolling Attack or Vertical Roll off the crouching Medium Kick
>
> **Crouching Medium Kick cancel into Hard Punch Rolling Attack, Level 1 Focus Attack**
>   The Focus Attack does a bit more damage, but this is useful if they end up blocking the combo, you can still stay on the offensive. You can even try charging the Focus Attack to level 2 or 3 and try to land a a crumple!
>
> **Crouching Medium Kick, Ultra**
>   This is a great way to land Blanka's Ultra if you have the timing down, just keep in mind you aren't canceling from the crouching Medium Kick, but instead you are waiting fr the MK to recover and then doing the Ultra. Your opponent will still be recovering from the C. MK attack and will end up being hit by the Ultra if you do it right!

Comment: Perhaps it would be good to post the main points of that article here in the answer, in case the source site goes away?

Comment: Good idea, added some major points.

Answer (score 2):

Ah Blanka, one of my favorite SF4 characters.  Here are a few additional useful tips in addition to the excellent ones Kevin Y posted:

1. Crossups - His best crossup combo is the jumping medium kick followed by jab leading right into a fierce electric thunder.
2. Against most skilled opponents, they will be prepared to face you and will constantly crouch + jab, making it difficult for you to perform a standard rolling attack on them.  In this situation, you have to fake them out, doing the standing fierce kick will look like you are starting the animation for a vertical roll, which can be used to your advantage.  Also mix in short and medium rolls.
3. A good wake-up move to pull is the EX rolling thunder attack, it not only gets you into the air to prevent throws, but will break armor and go through their fireball.
4. As for being aggressive or defensive, it entirely depends on your opponent's playing style.  Personally, I prefer to go on the aggressive with a nice mixup of vertical and horizontal rolls and pokes to keep them guessing.  Since Blanka has a lack of a fireball, going defensive is more difficult.
5. Blanka's throw move is very nice to use, it gives you a few seconds to think and helps run out the clock in your favor.
6. Down+Fierce goes under most fireballs, even Sagat's low fireball.  Don't overuse it or they'll start to expect it, but its a good one to have.  I sometimes lead off my fight with this move and catch them right off the bat.  Also, this is a great move to use if they are doing a straight up jump and you are too far away to move in to punish them easily.  This move covers a LOT of ground.
7. Don't always use the fierce rolls.  A lot of times you can do a medium or light roll and then throw them.  It tricks a lot of people if done right.
8. Blanka's other crossup move is the medium ground roll.  It is at the perfect speed where you can hit them on the weak side as they are getting up.  The fierce is too fast and hard to time.
9. Sometimes, even when they block my vertical roll, I go into electric thunder as soon as I hit the ground.  More often than not, this leads to a double hit, so you don't lose out entirely.
10. Last but not least, Blanka is a charge type character so you want to utilize [charge buffering](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/15011/street-fighter-charge-attacks/15017#15017)