# How can I properly perform a move with a full circle instruction?

Tags: street-fighter-iv, street-fighter-series

When I try to perform Zangief's Super attack, I need to perform a full circle movement of the joystick. I am not very experienced with performing such actions and when I try it I end up jumping instead of performing the move.

I would appreciate some tips on how to perform moves that include full circle motions properly.

Comment: I believe this question applies to all* games from the Street Fighter series. (* well, except the first one)

Answer (score 10):

Along with the 360, there are certain ultras, such as Zangief's that require a 720.

The not so well known knowledge for beginners is that, as Stof mentioned, the game is very tolerant for such moves.  What you only really need to perform, is a lazy 270 rather than the complete 360 before it recognizes the move as a full circle.

The standard accepted way of performing such a move is a HCB*, UB.

You'll want to hit the punch button as soon as you reach UB to prevent the jump.

For a 720, you can do: HCB, UB, HCB, UB.  The second HCB to UB needs to be performed extremely fast before Zangief has a chance to jump.  Zangief has a certain number of frames before the jump command actually kicks in, and as long as a move is performed within those frames, he will not jump.  (I believe the number is 6).

There are three standard ways of pulling off a 360:

1. Perform a normal attack.  This is usually the preferred way of doing the move.  Street fighter allows you to 'buffer' an attack up while doing another motion, and this is very similar to how to [buffer up a charge attack as well](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/15011/street-fighter-charge-attacks/15017#15017).
2. Perform a move as you are getting up.  There are risks and rewards associated with this type of move, its up to you to decide.
3. The least preferred method is to perform the circle move as you are jumping, but this is the most easy to perform for beginners, especially the 720.  However, this is a dead give away that you are trying to perform such a move.

For additional tricks, look up the "Walking 720" for ways of pulling off the move.

*HCB = half circle back, UB = up back

Comment: Splendid answer! I'm not much of a fighter person, and these sort of moves have always stumped me.

Comment: so there are no way to use an super attack of zangief while standing still?

Comment: @gunbuster363 if by standing still you mean not even attacking, then no.

Comment: @gunbuster363 In the SFIV series you can, but it requires "mad skillz": http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ISKfZgwRT4U

Answer (score 2):

You can try doing a light punch/kick before immediately doing the 360 degree motion. The attack animation will "lock" you so you won't jump.

Answer (score 2):

The game is extremely tolerant for such things actually. You don't need to do a full circle at all which makes it easier to avoid jumping.

I think the shortest manipulation you can do for a "full circle" special starts from the front goes down then back then back/up+punch/kick. As you can see, you spend very little time pressing Up and you do it at the end of the motion so it should be much easier to do the special without the game making you jump first. It'll take some training to get the motion right though :)

Answer (score 1):

As already stated the game engine allows for fuzzy input. You can input a 270° motion as already stated OR you can input the bare minimum.

Inputing the 4 cardinal directions (up, down, left, right) in any order and composition (down + left can either count as down OR left, but never as both - this is why 270 is enough) will be accepted as a full circle motion.

Knowing this you can abuse it to your benefit. Have you ever seen Zangiefs going forward and backwards, which translates to left and right, very fast before a pile diver? They do this as footsies plus they buffer 2 of the 4 required cardinal directions, they only need to input down and up + punch to execute the move.

So good players actually input: back, forward, down, up + punch. It is really easy and fast once you do it a few times. This also works with the ultra, but the directions are not as arbitrary. You have to execute 1 full circle and then another one. During both full circles you have to hit the 4 cardinal directions in any order.

So left, right, down, up, down, up, left, right + all punch will translate into ultra, but left, left, right, right, up, up, down, down + all punch will just give you ex pile diver (one full circle + 2 punches)

You cannot abuse the ultra motion that good, this is why most players just execute 1 full circle and a 270 for the ultra, as it comes more natural.