# What is the proper way for using a special move that requires charging?

Tags: street-fighter-iv, super-street-fighter-iv

I can't say I'm a professional (or even well versed) SF4 player, so pardon any terminology discrepancies I make.

Though I've had a copy of SSF4 lying around for quite a while, I've gotten into it only recently and came across an issue that has always bugged me in fighting games.

While some characters (such as Ryu) have very precise means of performing special moves, others (such as Guile) require charging directional input in order to pull off a special move. I find that this charge really gives away your intentions (unless you pull off the move during some insane combo. That's not what I'm talking about) and makes it difficult to react with a special move quickly.

When I'm playing as Ryu, my opponent has no way of knowing that I'm about to dish out a Hadoken, and if he happens to jump over me, I can counter with a Shoryuken without too much preparation.

However, when I'm playing as Guile and I want to pull off a sonic boom, then I either have to start backing away, or crouch back to hold my position, both rather obvious giveaways. Also, there's no quick way to react with a Flash Kick when someone is jumping at you.

Again, Guile is just an example, and I have these issues with most charge based moves. Is there a better way to use such moves that I'm missing, or do you simply have to use characters with such moves in a different manner when playing?

Comment: I realize this question may seem a duplicate of [this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/15011/street-fighter-charge-attacks), but I care more about keeping the element of surprise and being able to react than performing moves quickly.

Comment: It's not a dupe, as that is about spamming.  This is more about the metagame.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With charge characters, there's not much you can do to hide the fact that you are charging (for the most part, [sliding input buffers](http://sf4answers.com/questions/216/executing-links-in-combos) allow you to mask charge *somewhat*).

However, this is part of the balance of the game, moves that require a charge such as this usually have quick recovery time.

In your specific example, Guile has the fastest recovery time in the game with his projectiles (outside of Seth).

Ryu (even though he has a great projectile) has *some* recovery time and you *can* punish him easier than you would Guile.

Speaking about Guile specifically, you can perform a Sonic Boom *and* retain the charge for the Flash Kick.  If you hold the controller down and back, the charge counts for both down *and* back.  If you perform the Sonic Boom like so:

[image: DB][image: D][image: DF]

Then you'll be able to perform the Sonic Boom while *still* retaining the charge for the Flash Kick.  If someone jumps late enough, since you still have the joystick in the down position and retain the charge for the Flash Kick.

Note that joysticks with square gates make this *much* easier to perform than on pad (with a square gate joystick, you can move the stick along the bottom edge, as opposed to a pad where you have to roll your thumb across the D-pad or roll the thumbstick, which is round).