# How should I play Guile against Ryu/Ken users?

Tags: super-street-fighter-iv

I'm maining Guile and recently I've been on a lose streak against the same guy who is maining Ken/Ryu (switching one after another), the guy is not that skillful but the deal is:

Every now and then at start of the match he used to jump in at me probably he thinks I'd throw a sonic boom at start, but instead I always crouch down and hit him with flash kick. However, later on in the game, once in a while when he jumps in at me while I'm in crouch down position, I try to execute flash kick or crouch down + HP but none executed (I just appeared idle and I can´t figure out the reason) and I just get knocked out.

How do I improve my game playing as Guile against Ken or Ryu?

Comment: Sounds like you're suffering from input lag, which happens on high latency connections.

Comment: I want to agree with you in some way, unless there's some other explanation like pressing the buttons too late. Well I think I'll stick with the input lag cuz I'm feeling this way - one of the cons for playing online. :( Maybe next time when I cope with jump-ins, I'll try "back > down back" or "dash forward/backward", what do you suggest?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Guile, but his crouching hard punch is safe against most jump-in moves. I'd try to go with that, maybe follow up with sonic boom or flash kick. Other than this you could try to standing block the jump in, then perform a throw immediately.

Comment: which chars are you using?

Comment: I'm maining Gouken, but his anti-air moves won't very much help you for Guile. I use high-parry now and then, but decide block mostly. I have to watch out for safejumps that counter the high-party and throw me off or be ready to tech a throw when blocking. Many moves I can punish with standing hard kick, too.

Comment: [**This**](http://www.airryu.com/?p=26) is a Ryu guide for the matchup, but you can still use the information. It is from Canada's best Ryu player AirRyu. It might be a bit dated, but the information still applies.

Answer (score 3):

There are several things you should be doing against a Ryu or Ken as Guile.

1. Guile's all about getting in close and doing a lot of punch/kick mixes to keep the opponent off balance and guessing.  Once he gets in close, there are [a lot of things](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZXNs1N2LXxs) he can do to cause a lot of damage.
2. [Charge Buffer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/15017/3917) your sonic boom.  If he wants to go into a fireball fight with you, you can actually win (IN SSF4 they lowered charge time of sonic boom as well) because you build up your EX bar much faster.  This is most important, good use of the EX sonic boom can turn a fireball fight into your favor.
3. From what you've typed, it seems like you are sitting in the game a lot while crouched (i.e. turtling).  This only works if you have a huge health advantage over your target and the time is running out.
4. If you can't pull off a sonic boom or flash kick when you want to, it usually means you didn't charge enough.  As a guile, you should be charging buffering on every single move, even normal moves.

Some specific things to try:

- Lead with a slow sonic boom and walk in behind it to cover distance between you and your opponent.
- Add some throws and focus attacks into your repertoire, remember focus attacks can absorb 1 fireball (and most hits)
- Instead of jumping into him if he throws a fireball, try absorbing it with focus cancel, but don't absorb more than 1 at a time.  For the second one, either sonic boom it or jump straight up for the avoid.
- Patience, Guile takes a lot of patience, you have to mentally wear down your opponent and force them to come to you if you can build up a health advantage (don't let yourself get backed into a corner though).

Last thing you can try is watching some good Guiles play, even though Guile lost in this one (he was facing one of the best Ryu players), it demonstrates how he can hold his own in a fireball fight:

Comment: Thanks for the whole bunch of the basic principles with Guile against Ryu. I'll have to practice harder. The video you linked has been one of my favorites (daigo as my favorite player & lamerboi a top guile player which is what I am using).